# Is it KoTH if they don't fight each other?

Tags: discussion, tags, code-challenge, king-of-the-hill

I am planning on running a KoTH where each bot individually plays a game, it is a 1 player game so they don't fight each other. Is it still a KoTH or should I do it as a code-challenge?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) tag wiki:

> King-of-the-hill indicates a game where the submissions interact with and compete against each other in some form of game. Competitions which pit programs against each other without interaction should rather use [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge).

Comment: Well that works :)